# Картинка с белым фоном при экспорте

Tags: photoshop

Проблема в следующем: есть макет в psd, в нём содержится логотип, в самом макете он с прозрачным фоном, но если я начинаю его экспортировать в PNG, фон становится белым.

Также если открыть этот логотип на отдельной странице, фон тоже белый и картинка вовсе в .jpg. Как тогда на макете фон прозрачный?

Не пойму, в чем причина, ведь на главной странице макета фон прозрачный... (обрезать ровно не получается).

Вот скрин проблемы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

https://yadi.sk/d/aT_hbeijuqMry

Comment: Александр, попробуйте щелкнуть по слою с логотипом правой кнопкой мыши, выберите пункт "Преобразовать в смарт-объект", далее выделите все на макете комбинациями CTRL+A и CTRL+C, затем создайте новое окно **с прозрачным фоном** и вставьте изображение из буфера комбинацией CTRL+V.

Comment: Не получается. Всё равно белый фон.

Comment: Прикрепите ссылку на макет к вопросу

Comment: Прикрепил ссылку в вопросе.

Comment: картинка в шаблоне не с прозрачным фоном это jpeg. сделайте сохранить для веб выбрав пипеткой белый цвет и сделав его транспарентным

Answer (score 2):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С чего Вы взяли, что логотип с прозрачным фоном?
Он изначально вставлен с белой подложкой, которую можно удалить теркой, либо другими инструментами (волшебная палочка, выделение, ... )

Answer (score 1):

пример того как стоит поступить:

http://i.giphy.com/3o7TKHSw3HmYmNqOIg.gif (5.4 Мб)

Comment: @cheops, там 5.4 Мб, а ограничение на ресурсе в 2 Мб.